# Controlling term explosion with Biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, pubmed

I've been unable to find documentation on how to control explosion of terms when conducting a Biopython search of Medline/PubMed.

For example, if I search for `surgery, oral [MH]` on PubMed, it finds 69,926 matching publications.  (PubMed is said to automatically explode terms.)

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=surgery%2C+oral+%5BMH%5D&sort=date&show_snippets=off

But the code below returns a count of only 8561 publications.  Even more puzzling, the translation stack in the output appears to claim that the term was exploded.

```
import Bio.Entrez as Entrez
import pprint

search_handle = Entrez.esearch( 
                    db = "pubmed", 
                    term = "surgery, oral [MH]", 
                    rettype = 'uilist', 
                    retmax = 1,
                    )
search_results = Entrez.read(search_handle)
search_handle.close()
pprint.pprint( search_results.items() )
```

Here is the output:

```
[(u'Count', '8561'),
 (u'RetMax', '1'),
 (u'IdList', ['33499855']),
 (u'TranslationStack',
  [{u'Count': '8561', u'Field': 'MeSH Terms', u'Term': '"surgery, oral"[MeSH Terms]', u'Explode': 'Y'}, 'GROUP']),
 (u'TranslationSet',
  [{u'To': '"surgery, oral"[MeSH Terms]', u'From': 'surgery, oral[MH]'}]),
 (u'RetStart', '0'),
 (u'QueryTranslation', '"surgery, oral"[MeSH Terms]')]
```

How do I force Biopython to ask Medline to explode the term?  This is Biopython 1.75.  I am limited to Python 2.7.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Chris!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is surprisingly simple:

Just get rid of the comma `,` in your search term: Perform your search with `term="surgery oral [MH]"` instead of `term="surgery, oral [MH]"`.

With the former search, I currently receive a count of 69945 - the same number that I get when searching for *surgery, oral[mh]* on the PubMed web page.

The latter search term leads to a count of 8561, currently.

If you look carefully at your output, you can see that your original search term got translated into `"surgery, oral"[MeSH Terms]`. Entering that string (including the `"` quotes) on PubMed also gives you 8561 results - [MeSH Terms] just being the long form of [mh].

Comment: Thank you!  This is quite unexpected to me.  Why does this answer work?  The official MeSH term for the concept includes the comma.  The difference seems to be in the way the term is translated.  With the no-comma search, the search is translated into `"oral surgical procedures" [MeSH Terms]` in both PubMed and Entrez/Biopython.  But from MeSH (and common sense) the terms "oral surgical procedures" and "surgery oral" *should* not be the same.  I remain confused.  :-(